# What's the keyboard key of defocus in address bar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools, vimium

I was using extensions like Vimium, Saka Key( to use only keyboard to control web browser )

sometimes, I want to leave focus, in the current tab,
so that I can active those extensions with keyboard keys

e.g.

1.when cursor focus on an input element, I can press ESC key or move my cursor and click in blank space in this page, then I can press 'f' to active Vimium

2.when cursor focus in the address bar in google chrome, press ESC key just don't work, I don't want to move my cursor, then click, is there any keyboard shortcut to defocus in the address bar?

Answer (score -1):

Try pressing TAB. This moves me out of the address bar and I can use vimium again.

EDIT for more info:

I have also ran into this issue, where I press CTRL+l to move to the adress bar, but don't want to use my mouse to click back to the screen. I found that by pressing TAB, focus moves from the address bar to the first link on the page, and from here I can use Vimium again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: @Toto Edited my answer for more clarification now.